# Finding the shortest and longest word of a string in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find the shortest and longest word in a given string. If the entered string is "house tap mobile telephone" then the longest word should be telephone and shortest will be tap. I have already written the following functions. How do i find the index of the strings and find the shortest and longest word out of it?

```
---------Converting string into a list of strings and finding length of each word--------

stringConvert :: String -> [Int]
stringConvert x = map (length) (words x)

----------Find the longest word-----------

findLongestWord :: String -> Int
findLongestWord x = maximum(stringConvert x)

----------Find the shortest word-----------

findShortestWord :: String -> Int
findShortestWord x = minimum(stringConvert x)
```

Comment: To say thank you on this site, *upvote* (click the up arrow for) each answer that helped you, and *accept* (click the tick mark for) the answer you think is best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looking for a certain word, the signatures of your functions should be

```
findLongestWord :: String -> String
findShortestWord :: String -> String
```

The `stringConvert` function you have implemented has the right idea, but it is a bit problematic because the result doesn't have the information which word is associated with which length. It might be better to separate splitting the string into a word list from the length calculation, and there is a handy function called `comparing` that actually removes the need for the `stringConvert` function altogether.

```
import Data.List (maximumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

findLongestWord :: String -> String
findLongestWord s = maximumBy (comparing length) (words s)
```

`maximumBy` is similar to `maximum` but it takes as the first parameter a function that should be used to compare two items. `comparing` is a higher-order function that can be used to convert a function of type `a -> b` (where `b`is some type that can be compared, i.e. `Ord b => a -> b` if you are already familiar with type constraints) into a comparison function between two `a`'s (i.e. a function of type `a -> a -> Ordering`).

The shortest word can be found in a similar manner.

Comment: Note however that your solution will recalculate the length of strings for every comparison, making it slow for long strings, as `length` is O(n). For many long strings, dave4420's solution will be faster, as it "caches" the lengths before sorting.

Comment: @PeterWortmann: Yeah, that's a very good point. I was definitely optimizing for readability rather than performance and should have made that clear in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Think about the problem differently.

```
import Data.Function (on)

stringConvert :: String -> [(String, Int)]
stringConvert s = map (\word -> (word, length word)) (words s)

findLongestWord :: String -> String
findLongestWord s = fst $ maximumBy (compare `on` snd) (stringConvert s)
-- findShortestWord is similar
```

I'm assuming that you only really cared about the index so you could use it to lookup the word. Instead I'm carrying the word around with its length.

If you really do want to know the index, you'll want something like

```
stringConvert :: String -> [((Int, String), Int)]
stringConvert s = zipWith (\index word -> ((index, word), length word)) [0..] (words s)
```

The type of `findLongestWord` will then be different, but its definition remains the same.

**Edit:** This trick is known as [“decorate-sort-undecorate” or “Schwartzian transform”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) and is useful in other languages as well.

**2nd edit:** Data.Function should have come with your compiler, but here's the definition of `on` in the meantime:

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
(.*.) `on` f = \x y -> f x .*. f y
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your approach is much better than what i had in mind. I get an error saying "cant find imported module Data.Function" how do i fix this?

Comment: Data.Function is part of the base libraries, so you should have it installed. Are you using GHC or Hugs? Which version?

Comment: I use GHC, so I can't help you with your library problem, sorry. Try asking about it as a new question.

Comment: As a side note `(\w -> (w, length w))` is `(length >>= flip (,))` in pointfree.

Comment: @Matvey I find `(id &&& length)` more readable, although neither are good to show to a beginner, imo.

Comment: @Sindu_ Hugs hasn't been updated in over 5 years. http://cvs.haskell.org/Hugs/pages/latest.htm  Haskell Platform is probably better for you. http://www.haskell.org/platform