# Stuck - Practice exam Q for Haskell coding: Return the longest String in a list of Strings

Tags: string, haskell, mapping, fold

The full practice exam question is:

> Using anonymous functions and mapping functions, define Haskell
>   functions which return the longest String in a list of Strings, e.g.
>   for [“qw”, “asd”,”fghj”, “kl”] the function should return “fghj”.

I tried doing this and keep failing and moving onto others, but I would really like to know how to tackle this. I have to use mapping functions and anonymous functions it seems, but I don't know how to write code to make each element check with each to find the highest one.

I know using a mapping function like "foldr" can make you perform repeating operations to each element and return one result, which is what we want to do with this question (check each String in the list of Strings for the longest, then return one string).

But with foldr I don't know how to use it to make checks between elments to see which is "longest"... Any help will be gladly appreciated.

So far I've just been testing if I can even use `foldr` to test the length of each element but it doesn't even work:

```
longstr :: [String] -> String
longstr lis = foldr (\n -> length n > 3) 0 lis
```

I'm quite new to haskell as this is a 3 month course and it's only been 1 month and we have a small exam coming up

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call a fold a mapping function. However, since the fold function has two parameters - the current element and the accumulator - perhaps one way to use a fold could be to assign the longest element so far to the accumulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say they're looking for a simple solution:

```
longstr xs = foldr (\x acc -> if length x > length acc then x else acc) "" xs
```

`foldr` is like a loop that iterates on every element of the list `xs`. It receives 2 arguments: `x` is the element and `acc` (for accumulator) in this case is the longest string so far.

In the condition if the longest string so far is longer than the element we keep it, otherwise we change it.

Comment: Make ``foldr1`` out of that and you can remove the empty string

Comment: @ThreeFx That would be a slightly different function, because of their differing behavior on the empty list input. Which one you want depends on if you want it to throw an error on an empty list or give the empty string (or do something else).

Answer (score 3):

Another idea:

1. Convert to a list of tuples: (length, string)
2. Take the maximum of that list (which is some pair).
3. Return the string of the pair returned by (2).

Haskell will compare pairs (a,b) lexicographically, so the pair returned by (2) will come from the string with largest length.

Now you just have to write a maximum function:

```
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
```

and this can be written using `foldr` (or just plain recursion.)

To write the `maximum` function using recursion, fill in the blanks:

```
maximum [a] = ???       -- maximum of a single element
maximum (a:as) = ???    -- maximum of a value a and a list as (hint: use recursion)
```

The base case for `maximum` begins with a single element list since `maximum []` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Ok, I mapped out the basic idea of how to do this, I can't find anything on ho to directly "take the maximum of that list". Could you please tell me the method to do that?

Comment: I've added some more to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the list to a list of tuples, consisting of (length, string). Sort by length (largest first) and return the string of the first element.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9157940/127059 has an answer as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, this sounds like it will defintely work. My problem however is still the same - I don't know how to "sort" or the recursive pattern or just pattern in comparing elements in a list, tuple, etc and sorting them.

Comment: Answer the question, a link if not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of building what you want from the bottom up.

```
maxBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> a
maxBy f x y = case compare (f x) (f y) of
 LT -> y
 _  -> x

maximumBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> Maybe a
maximumBy _ [] = Nothing
maximumBy f l  = Just . fst $ foldr1 (maxBy snd) pairs
 where
    pairs = map (\e -> (e, f e)) l 

testData :: [String]
testData = ["qw", "asd", "fghj", "kl"]

test :: Maybe String
test = maximumBy length testData

main :: IO ()
main = print test
```